# bibliography url going out of page

Tags: biblatex, line-breaking

[image]I have typed this code

```
@misc{MilanRajne.2013,
 author = {{Milan Rajne}},
 editor = {{Texas Instruments}},
 year = {2013},
 title = {Generate your own commutation table: Trapezoidal control 3-phase BLDC motors using hall sensors},
 url ={https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/motordrivecontrol/archive/2013/11/08/generate-your-own-commutation-table-trapezoidal-control-3-phase-bldc-motors\\\\-using-hall-sensors}
}
```

My url in the LaTeX output is going out of page.
I tried new line command but its not working. How I should  enter new line?

Comment: Do you load the `url` and/or `hyperref` packages? Have you tried adding the option `hyphens` when loading the `url` package? Separately, do you use biblatex (if so, with which style) or bibtex (if so, with which bibliography style)?

Comment: Do you actually use the `biblatex` package? The questions tags suggest you do but it is not clear from the question itself. A [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) is needed!

Comment: its happening like this

Comment: @d.r A screenshot is not very useful, either answer the questions about the packages you use or add a MWE.

Comment: Please tell us exactly how you load the `biblatex` and `hyperref` packages.

Comment: Any news here? We really need that [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) of your code to be able to help. If I delete the `\\\\` in your `.bib` entry, the output looks fine here. (Except that it should be `author = {Milan Rajne},` and that TI is probably not the editor.)